# Meaning of "six-three"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "six-three" in this excerpt from a [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/03/us/justices-approve-strip-searches-for-any-offense.html?pagewanted=2&_r=1)?

> “Turn around,” Mr. Florence, in an interview last year, recalled being
>   told by jail officials. “Squat and cough. Spread your cheeks.”
>   “I consider myself a man’s man,” said Mr. Florence, a finance
>   executive for a car dealership. “**Six-three**. Big guy. It was
>   humiliating. It made me feel less than a man.”

I could not find on Google nor Urban dictionary.

Comment: A hard one to figure out for those of us who are used to metric ;-)

Comment: @aaamos: 190 cm, then... 8^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's his height. Six feet and three inches.

Comment: Trivial if you know it, but I can imagine it could be tricky finding the answer to *this* one just using Google!

Comment: Had he said "Five-O" instead of "Six-three" it might have meant 5' 0" tall, or it could have meant he was a police officer.  If "Five-O" was followed by "Big guy," though, that would mean he's a cop for sure.